# How to replace a GLSL uniform array with a 1D texture

Tags: arrays, opengl, glsl, textures, fragment-shader

I am trying to get Ardor3D's terrain system to work on SM3.0 hardware.

The current GLSL fragment shader uses a uniform vec2 array to pass an array of xy coordinates into the fragment shader.

As dynamic indexed uniform arrays only work on SM4.0+ hardware, to get it running on SM3.0 I need to replace it with a 1D float texture.

The current array looks like this:
`uniform vec2 sliceOffset[8];`

and is accessed like this:
`vec2 offset = sliceOffset[int(unit)];`

I am very experienced with OpenGL and GLSL so I am having some problems doing the conversion.

So far I have done this:
Create a 1D texture
- width = 8
- format = RGBA32F

Create a 1D buffer for the texture

- width = 8 * 4 = 32 floats, or 32 * 4 = 32 bytes large

  fill the float buffer like this:

`[x0,y0,0,0,x1,y1,0,0,x2,y2,0,0,x3,y3,0,0,x4,y4,0,0,x5,y5,0,0,x6,y6,0,0,x7,y7,0,0]`

Create a 1D sampler for the texture

- min filter = nearest, no mip maps

  mag filter = nearest

  wrap mode = clamp to edge

In the GLSL I define the sampler as:
`uniform sampler1D sliceOffset;`

And accesses it:

```
vec2 getSliceOffset(float unit)
{
 float texCoord = (unit * 2.0f + 1.0f) / (2.0f * 8.0f);
 vec2 offset = texture1D(sliceOffset, texCoord);
 return offset;
}
```

But it is broken.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you're showing looks right. "It is broken" is not very descriptive though. What are the symptoms ?

Some things that you don't show that may be wrong:

- 2 samplers using the same texture unit.
- type issues in the texture data (although if you're experienced, I doubt it)

One additional thing you could try: use a texture2d instead, with just height=1. DX does not require 1d texture support, so depending on hardware, the opengl support for it might be emulated. You can try to stay away from such emulation.

Comment: I have tried outputting the color returned from the texture to gl_FragColor so I can do more debugging. The texture responds to changes so the sampler is using the correct texture.

Comment: So I wrote this to the buffer [1.0, 0, 0, 0, ... 1.0, 0, 0, 0]. Now I would expect the result to be red, but I get blue!, if I set the dataformat to GL_BGRA I then get red. Also if I use unit = 0, 2, 4, ... I get blue, but for unit = 1, 3, 5, ... I get black. Does that help?

Comment: Also can someone verify that the texCoord calculation is correct?

Comment: @Leith. Please update your question with the call to glTexImage1D and its data.

Answer (score 1):

The texCoord calculation is correct. It was confusing at first since I would've done (unit + .5) / 8.0, but it's the same.

One thing still worries me though. Don't you need to write .rg at the end of your sampler statement since the texFetch will be a vec4? I'm surprised that your compiler isn't complaining about it.

Try:

```
texture1D(sliceOffset, texCoord).rg;
```

Comment: Sorry that I missed that, but I was using it. It missed it when I was creating that example. Any ideas about why I am getting weird colors in my debug?

Comment: I can't figure it out. The only problem it could really be is an incorrect format, but that looks fine too.